# I keep getting virus infection notifications and don't know how to stop them

Tags: macos, notifications, virus

[image]They are popping up multiple times a day. Is there any way to block them?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like a macOS dialog/notification, where exactly does it show up?

Comment: I agree with @nohillside.  That looks like a webpage modal, not a genuine macOS notification banner.  Where are you seeing these?

Comment: Yes, this is an attempt to infect you, by getting you to click on it. It's essentially a web pop-up window. What browser are you using?

Comment: These messages show up in Notifications on the right side of the screen. Using Safari 15.6.1. So how do I block a webpage modal?

Comment: It’s either a Safari plugin generating the modal/notification or something that you installed.  The first thing to confirm is that this is limited to your user profile only.  Create a new user account (just for testing), log into that and see if it goes away.

Comment: Logged in to a test account. Seems clean so far.

Comment: You agreed to notifications from a dodgy web site, that is now sending you false notifications to entice you to click on the links and install their malware.  Remove that notification permission.

Comment: Thanks. Now how do I track that down?

Comment: Found the culprit. Thanks to everybody that responded.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday, after running into a rogue website, and it was easy to fix once you know how to.

Usually Safari is set up so that any website can ask for permission to send you notifications. You click on yes or no somewhere, and if you clicked no you don't get notifications. If you click yes, they can send you notifications. Note that is all the website can do: Send you a notification. If the notification tricks you into doing something stupid, like buying some antivirus software, that's down to you. The notification can't do anything. Of course if I send you a notification then I can  put anything into it, for example "your Mac has been infected by 316 viruses and they are multiplying".

To turn it off: Go to Safari, "Settings..." in the Safari menu. Tap on "Websites" between "Privacy" and "Profiles". Pick "Notifications" at the bottom on the left side. This shows you all websites that have asked for permission to send you notifications. And one of them where you allowed to send them notifications is the rogue one; all you need is to change it from "Allow" to "Deny", and it can't ever ask you again.